# When to move JOIN operation from database layer to service layer?

Tags: sql, performance, backend

Considering this case where we have 2 tables. The requirement is to implement a function to select the top 10 records (ordered by some rules) from `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`, where `table_a.id == table_b.a_id == X`. There are two options:

1. Using `JOIN` to query the SQL;
2. Making 2 selection queries from db: `SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id = X` and `SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE a_id = X`, fetching 10 records from each query (let's assume the ordering is correct in this case) in memory, then join them in the code (using a for loop and a hashtable or sth like that).

I've heard that `JOIN` might lower the **system** performance (was "db performance" here but that was wrong)(see follow up below for reference). Besides, in this case we only queries for 10 results at maximum, which is acceptable to load them all in memory then join them there.

My question is, is there a general guideline in the industry, to say under what circumstances would we recommend using `JOIN` in database layer instead of doing it in memory, and when to do the opposite?

============

Follow up:

So here's some reason/scenario I've read for "moving JOIN from database layer to 
 service layer":

1. If we are joining multiple tables, they will all be locked at once. And if the operation take times and the service requires low response time, it might block other executions;
2. Hard to maintain in the big system. Changes of the tables that are involved in `JOIN` might make the query broken.
3. There might be some historical reason for those complicated systems, that data might be migrated/created in different db (or db systems, say one table in DynamoDB and the other one in Postgres), which makes `JOIN` in the database layer impossible.

Comment: "I've learned that JOIN might lower the db performance" - er, what? Relational Databases are designed to join tables and do it efficiently

Comment: There is never a reason to use your second option over a JOIN. You've been  badly misinformed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you. Is it better?

Comment: @MitchWheat @KenWhite First of all, thank you for responding! So always doing `JOIN` in this case? Is there any other case (and reason) that we would want to avoid `JOIN`?

Comment: @idk The issue here isn't avoiding join, rather it would be how might you speed up the join, using something like an index, for example.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks a lot! Yeah "speeding up the join" instead of "avoiding join" makes a lot of sense. Besides, I've added some follow up in the question, what do you think about them?

Comment: It _is_ possible to join across different databases, in most RDBMS.  You should spend some time reviewing a good SQL tutorial before you proceed any further.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It might be possible to join across different dbs under some circumstances, but what if they are even in different db systems? say table_a is in dynamoDB and table_b is in postgres?

Comment: If joins werent there, ppl wud be putting all information in one big table. Normalising in multiple tables and joins speed up the queries. U shud check the execution plan..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To answer simply, it depends.**

- Generally, it is preferable to do data operations closer to data, instead of bringing them higher up in the layers and handle data operations. You can see many PL/SQL based implementations, where they do operations closer to data. Languages like PL/SQL(ORACLE) or TSQL(SQL Server) are designed to do complex data operations.
- But, if you have an application, which brings data from disparate systems and have to join between them, you have to do them in memory.

  > 1. If we are joining multiple tables, they will all be locked at once. And if the operation take times and the service requires low response time, it might block other executions;

Readers are not blocking other readers. They have something called sharedlock. Also, once the read operation is over, shared lock is released. As, @TimBiegeleisen, you can create indexes to speed up read operations, based on the need. It is always preferable to read only needed columns(projection), needed rows(filtering).

> 2. Hard to maintain in the big system. Changes of the tables that are involved in JOIN might make the query broken.

As long as you are selecting only the needed columns, instead of SELECT *, you should not be having issues. If many changes are coming, you can considering creating SCHEMA BINDING View, to avoid schema changes to the underlying tables.

> 3. There might be some historical reason for those complicated systems, that data might be migrated/created in different db (or db systems, say one table in DynamoDB and the other one in Postgres), which makes JOIN in the database layer impossible.

Design the application for current need. Dont assume that something like that will happen in future and design for that and compromise on current application performance. If there is a definite future need, go for in-memory operations. Otherwise, better go for database JOINs.